# How can I make the username have a solid background so it doesn't show the text it overlaps?

Tags: html, css, hover, position, absolute

As you can see, the username "ladybug" overlaps,but I want a solid background so that the larger text in the back doesn't show. My intention is for people's ability to see which user typed which word on hover.[image]

Comment: Please leave a snippet of your code so developers can troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

would need to see your code to give a precise answer.
But from just looking at the picture id say give the username a z-index and a darker background color, should solve your problem